# How to compare BCM4708 with an Intel i5 M520 CPU for router and NAS

Tags: cpu-architecture

I currently have an Intel i5 M520 based computer running as a linux based router +  + Asterisk box + backup server file server [ rsnapshot and AES encrypted disk ].   From a CPU point of view I'm sure its overkill as the load sits at < 0.1 - but the box is old, noisy and has a dodgy BIOS and I want to replace it.

I have an unused ASUS RT-AC68U router with a BCM4708 CPU which, along with an external hard drive should be able to largely fill the same role and replace my old Belkin Access Point, but I'm unsure what the performance of this router will be.

Being  that the BCM4708 and X86 architectures are entirely different, I don't appear to be able to use CPUBoss or CPUBenchmark websites - is there any way to get a broad-strokes comparison of the CPU performance of each system, short of actually configuring the ASUS router ?

Comment: Had to use a broadwell version of your chip but compared it to a Apple A5X which is comparable to the chip your interested in here: https://versus.com/en/apple-a9-vs-intel-core-i5-2537m-vs-apple-a5x-vs-intel-core-m-5y10 disregard the others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is going to be very hard to compare - the router uses the BCM4708, which is based on 1 GHz Arm dual core - AP CPU but optimized for networking.

So in terms of pure computing power the i5 will be much faster, however for use as a router you are being limited by its north and south bridge, as well as the networking cards. And there lies the issue in comparing just the CPU via benchmarks.

So since I am using he RT-AC68U at home and I am transferring VERY large files both up/down I would say go for it. Not because better CPU but because it is quiet, stable, uses less energy and also because the WiFi performance and reach is absolutely amazing - [see here](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/networking-and-wi-fi/modem-routers/asus-rt-ac68u-1262664/review/2)

Comment: Compare the CPU to a Apple A5X, since the A5X and BCM4708 are nearly identical identical since they are both based on the same Cortex A9